# Absinthe dataloader: no function clause matching in anonymous fn/3 in Absinthe.Resolution.Helpers.dataloader/2

Tags: graphql, elixir, absinthe

The integration between Absinthe and Dataloader is quite new for me, so any help is welcome.

I'm running into the following error:

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in anonymous fn/3 in Absinthe.Resolution.Helpers.dataloader/2
```

My `PostType`:

```
defmodule MyApp.Schema.Types.PostType do
  use Absinthe.Schema.Notation
  import Absinthe.Resolution.Helpers, only: [dataloader: 1]

  object :post_type do
    field(:id, :id)
    field(:title, :string)
    field(:body, :string)
    field(:published, :boolean)
    field :user, :user_type, resolve: dataloader(:user)
  end

  input_object :post_input_type do
    field(:title, non_null(:string))
    field(:body, non_null(:string))
    field(:published, non_null(:boolean))
  end
end
```

Schema Mutation:

```
@desc "Create a post"
    field :create_post, type: :post_type do
      arg(:input, non_null(:post_input_type))
      middleware(Authorize, :any)
      resolve(&Resolvers.PostResolver.create_post/3)
    end
```

Resolver:

```
def create_post(_, %{input: input}, %{context: %{current_user: current_user}}) do
    Map.merge(input, %{user_id: current_user.id})
    |> Blog.create_post()
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to the `dataloader` helper should be a module, not an atom.

For illustration, I will assume your `User` module is defined in `MyApp.Accounts.User` and that you have a file called `accounts.ex`.

Inside `accounts.ex`, you should have this:

```
  def data() do
    Dataloader.Ecto.new(Repo)
  end
```

Then change the user field in your post type to use this:

```
field :user, :user_type, resolve: dataloader(User)
```

I can help more if it's still not working. I'm currently trying to build an app using Absinthe so it's fresh in my brain.

Comment: thanks for your response. I'm currently getting `    ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in anonymous fn/3 in Absinthe.Resolution.Helpers.dataloader/2`. Also could you explain a bit about the usage of the data function in Accounts.ex?